# Does anyone know how to get text of right size of image without the background of the text stretching or the text going below the image?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

What it currently looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQeK5.png)

What I want it to look like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMcmm.png)

When every I uses css grid the text background stretches to the size of the image or it will end up being below the image even though there is a lot of empty space on the right size.

MY HTML

```
    <div class="Last-Part">
    <div class="Image">
<img src="https://cdn.jpegmini.com/user/images/slider_puffin_jpegmini_mobile.jpg">
</div>
    <div class="box4">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim4
  </div>
    <div class="box5">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo5
    
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
   .Last-Part div{
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
}
.Last-Part div:nth-child(odd){
    background: #eee;

}
.Last-Part{
    grid-column-gap: 1em;
    top: 50%;
    transition: translate(-50%, 50%);
    display: grid;
}
 .box4{
    align-items: end;
    width: 400px;
 }

.box5{
    width: 400px;

}
.Image{
    width: 510px;
}
img{

  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed some stuff in your code
[image: screenshot]

```
 <div class="Last-Part">
   <div class="Image">
     <img src="https://cdn.jpegmini.com/user/images/slider_puffin_jpegmini_mobile.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <div class="box4">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim4
     </div>
     <div class="box5">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo5

     </div>
     <div class="box4">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo5

     </div>
   </div>

 </div>
```

By using *flex* and *fit-content* you can easily achieve the layout you described.

```
 .Last-Part div {
   text-align: center;
   background: #ddd;
   padding: 1em;
   height: fit-content;
 }

 .Last-Part div:nth-child(odd) {
   background: #eee;

 }

 .Last-Part {
   display: flex;
   grid-column-gap: 1em;
   transition: translate(-50%, 50%);
 }

 .box4 {
   align-items: end;
   width: 400px;
 }

 .box5 {
   width: 400px;

 }

 .Image {
   width: 510px;
 }

 img {

   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
 }
```

Comment: It would be better to provide the code using an online code editor like https://codepen.io/pen/ or https://jsfiddle.net/ so that OP or other users can play around with it. Anyway, good answer.

Comment: @FotisPapadamis that's advised against on SO as links can expire from those sites. There's a runnable code editor built in to stack so it's best to use that

Answer (score 0):

Is this how you mean:

```css
.Last-Part div {
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
}

.Last-Part div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

.Last-Part {
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
  display: grid;
  width: fit-content;
}

.box4 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / 2;
  align-items: end;
  width: 400px;
}

.box5 {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 2 / 2;
  width: 400px;
}

.Image {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  width: 510px;
}

img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Last-Part">
  <div class="Image">
    <img src="https://cdn.jpegmini.com/user/images/slider_puffin_jpegmini_mobile.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="box4">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim4
  </div>
  <div class="box5">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo5

  </div>
</div>
```

With `grid-area` the areas are specified as `row-start / column-start / row-end / column-end`

Comment: Thanks for the solution this help me alot as a beginner in html and css :)